# Vectorized solution to assignment to specific rows by columns in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I have three matrices:

```
a<-sapply(1:300, function(x)  sample(1:100,100*0.8,replace=F))

b<-sapply(1:300, function(x) sample(1:2,100*0.8, replace=TRUE)) 

c<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=100, ncol=300)
```

I would like to assign to do the following assignment:

1. select those rows in `c[,1]` that are in `a[,1]` and assign b[,1] to them.
2. do this for all `c[,1:300]`, `a[,1:300]`, `b[,1:300]`

For one column I would do:

```
c[a[,1],1]<-b[,1]
```

but I would like to do this for all columns.

Is there a vectorized solution to this?

Comment: Are the column replacements really independent or do you want to match the entire row?

Comment: they are independent because different rows will be assigned in different columns

Answer (score 1):

Considering what it sounds like you're trying to do, I would actually just use a `for` loop:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- sapply(1:300, function(x)  sample(1:100,100*0.8,replace=F))
B <- sapply(1:300, function(x) sample(1:2,100*0.8, replace=TRUE)) 
C <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=100, ncol=300)

for (i in 1:ncol(C)) {
  C[A[, i], i] <- B[, i] 
}
```

In particular, since `C` is already preallocated, this will be very fast.